# How much more efficient is php_apc than memcached?

Tags: php, memcached, apc

There are various problems when using php_apc with symfony,

If the boost is not so significant,I'm going to replace apc with memcached.

Answer (score 8):

APC and memcached are not the same things :

Fisrt of all, APC has two roles :

- It's an opcode cache *(which means each PHP page will generally require less CPU, as it remove the "compilation" part ; the first time we enabled APC as an opcode cache, CPU load on our webservers went from something like 80% to something like 40-50%)*
- It's also a non-distributed data cache

  - which means, if you have several servers, that each one of your servers has a local copy of the cache
  - which also means there is a pretty low limit on the amount of data you can store in cache

And for memcached :

- It's only a data-cache
- It's distributed

  - i.e. no limit on the number of servers in a memcached cluster
  - i.e. no limit on the amount of cache you can have

You can use either APC or memcached, or both, as a data-cache *(that's what we are doing on the project I'm currently working on : some data are cached in APC, and some others using memcached)*.

But, if you want some opcode cache, you'll have to go with APC *(or eAccelerator ; but not sure it's well maintained)*.

Comment: What's the version of PHP and apc respectively?

Comment: Almost last "stable" version of PHP 5.2 *(i.e. something like 5.2.9 or 5.2.10)*, and last "stable" version of APC *(i.e. 3.0.19)*

Comment: I've heard apc is stable with PHP5.2,but I'm already using PHP5.3,and the apc version is 3.1.3.0,which seems buggy

Comment: Considering APC 3.1.x is still in beta, it might ; did you check its bug tracker ( http://pecl.php.net/bugs/search.php?cmd=display&status=Open&package_name[]=APC ) ? Did you try getting the last version from SVN ( http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/apc/ ) -- not sure it'll help, but who knows ?

Answer (score 4):

**[See this please :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815041/memcached-vs-apc-which-one-should-i-choose)**

> Memcached is a distributed caching
>   system, whereas APC is non-distributed
>   - and mainly an opcode cache.
>
> If (and only if) you have a web
>   application which has to live on
>   different webservers (loadbalancing),
>   you have to use memcache for
>   distributed caching. If not, just
>   stick to APC and its cache.
>
> You should always use an opcode cache,
>   which APC is (also APC will get
>   integrated into php6 iirc, so why not
>   start using it now).
>
> You can/should use both for different
>   purposes.

Comment: @user198729: then you should go for memecache :) by the way there are big apps already using apc.

Comment: @user198729 Could you document your comment ? Because almost every php server out there use APC as an opcode caching system without problems. (And yes I know you posted that in feb 2010 but i'm using it for a long time).