# CMS Database design - Master database or Multi-Db per site

Tags: database, database-design, memcached

I am in process of designing my CMS that I am about to create. I was thinking about the database and how I want to go by approaching it.

Do you think its best to create 1 master database for all my clients websites? or Should I have 1 database per site?

What is the benefits and negatives on both approaches? I am always thinking about the future so I was thinking about implementing memcache or APC cache to the project, to offer an option to my client.

Just trying to learn the best practices and what other developers apporach would be

Comment: for the APC/memcached question, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815041/memcached-vs-apc-which-one-should-i-choose

Comment: You should think about the following - (clients) business is good, lots of customers, maybe they want to be outsourcing chasing of customers or other tasks that require access to your data - would be a lot simpler if you have one db.

Even if it is a completely custom solution, that can be modulised, and will save you a lot of work in the future if you had one db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run both.  My business chooses to separate client-specific data into separate tables so that if one happens to go corrupt, not all are taken down.  In an ideal world this might never happen, but murphy's law....It does seem very easy to find things with them separated.  You will know with 100% certainty that one client's content will never show up on another's page.

If you do go down that route, be prepared to create scripts that build and configure databases for you.  There's nothing fun about building a great system and having demand for it, only to spend your time manually setting up DB's and installs all day long.  Also, setting db names is one additional step that's not part of using a single db table--it's a headache that will repeat itself seemingly over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

Develop the single master DB. It will take a small amount of additional effort and add a little bit more complexity to the database design, but will give you a few nice features. The biggest is being able to share data between sites.

Designing for a master database means that you have the option to combine sites when it makes sense, but also lets you install a master per site. Best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1):

It depends greatly upon the amount of customization each client will require. If you forsee clients asking for many one-off features specific to their deployment, separate databases based off of a single core structure might make sense. I would highly recommend trying to make any customizations usable by all clients though, and keep all structure defined in one place/database instead of duplicating it across multiple databases. By using one database, you make updating the structure straightforward and the implementation consistent across all sites so they can all use the same CMS code.