# Magento - APC Caching, weird basket behaviour

Tags: magento

Has anyone ever noticed any weird behaviour with regards to the shopping cart in magento when apc caching is enabled?

I have a situation where it looks as though extra items and/or different items are being added when the user adds something.

Its very strange and aparantly random but only seems to occur when we have apc enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This answer touches on what might be going on:

[Memcached vs APC which one should I choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815041/memcached-vs-apc-which-one-should-i-choose)

Simply move to memcache and your troubles should be resolved.

Comment: @ʍǝɥʇɐɯ - thanks for the input.  The thing is though, I have had apc running on several other maagento sites previously without this issue.  This tends to suggest that apc should work fine with magento

Comment: More than one Magento build on the same server?

Comment: Yes, using the prefix in local.xml

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try and clear APC's cache, both system cache and user cache.

Note that there is a difference between regular APC cache from CLI and Web based entries, and from what I've gathered you can't simply call it from CLI it has to be from a web request like so:

```
system('wget --spider --quiet http://localhost/apc/clear_apc_cache.php');
```

clear_apc_cache.php would contain:

```
apc_clear_cache('user');
```

More details: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-clear-cache.php

and note the Cache type Parameter:

> If cache_type is "user", the user
>   cache will be cleared; otherwise, the
>   system cache (cached files) will be
>   cleared.