# Magento - Random products being added to shopping cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have an issue at the moment where random products are being added to the shopping cart.  They are being added when the user adds a legitimate item to the shopping cart.  The problem appears random in that sometimes only 1 extra product will be added but other times there may be 2,3 or I have seen up to 11 extra products being added.

Additionally, I have noticed that the line totals for items in the cart are showing as doubled i.e. a product costs £21 and there is only 1 in the cart but the cart total is £42

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
As an update, the issue is in the database somewhere.  We have a test site which runs on a different database.  If I move the database from the affected site to the test site then the test site also has the same issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622218/magento-apc-caching-wierd-basket-behaviour/6627286 duplicate?

Comment: NO - the previous question is specific to apc.  There is no apc involved here

Comment: Do you have any extensions enabled, especially cart related ones? Did you customize any of the cart-related code?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue and think we have it fixed:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/295235/

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
truncate sales_flat_quote; 
truncate sales_flat_quote_address; 
truncate sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate; 
truncate sales_flat_quote_address_item; 
truncate sales_flat_quote_item; 
truncate sales_flat_quote_item_option; 
truncate sales_flat_quote_payment; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

it might be related to your problem - hope it helps (try it on a backed up site / dev site first!!!)

View6com