# php array vs database for static data

Tags: php, mysqli, associative-array

I have an associative array in php consisting of about 4k elements.
Product Id and Product Name
a sample row:

```
'434353', 'TeaCups'
```

So no big data. In fact the whole php array file is about 80kb.
This is static data, so I won't be changing, deleting any data.

Considering the size of the array and the number of elements in it,
Would it be better to access data from the array or I should create
a database instead?

The data might be read about 20k times a day.

PS: Each time the data will be read, I will be fetching exactly **one**
element

Comment: Accessing a database is much slower than accessing an array in memory. 80KB is very litle memory these days.

Comment: If it's being read that often you might want to consider APC or memcached for keeping the data in memory.

Comment: It's a no brainer, avoid db for that since you're not querying anything and you don't need the overhead of connecting to the db.

Comment: @SeanKenny Thanks, I was going to ask for that in another question.

Comment: @SeanKenny Do you recommend APC or memcached for this specific case?

Comment: i don't have the expertise to opine so I'll defer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815041/memcached-vs-apc-which-one-should-i-choose

Answer (score 1):

If this is static data, I recommend you store this data in a JSON format as a file, that you can access via PHP using the `fopen()` function.

However, if the data becomes bigger, like lets say, 2 GB, or even 200 MB, unless if you have a supercomputer, you should use the database and query from there.

Note that databases are usually only useful when you have a lot of information, or if you have too much information to process in a regular JSON.

Comment: I have opted for APC and array method. I dont suppose storing it in a json file, and reading/converting it to an array would be better than having
the array itself stored in RAM.